# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type bit Report Builder

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005, reportbuilder

I have a query that I use in a Report Builder.
The query in **Maindataset**

```
select 
customer_id
,first_name
,last_name
,case when customer_gender=0 then 'Man' 
when customer_gender=1 then 'women'
else null as gender 
,phone
,email
,city
from [customers]
```

Becuase I want add Gender as parameter (Appear As Man and Women),
I already create **Genderdataset**

```
select
case when customer_gender=0 then 'Man' 
when customer_gender=1 then 'women'
else null as G
from [customers]
```

when I click on run, the error message appear

> conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Man' to data type bit.

THANKS

Comment: Which query is failing? Test them in SSMS or something similar. Having said that, if the genderdataset is going to be used to supply values to a parameter (which I assume is going to be passed to your dataset query) then you don't need a query to do this, you can set the parameter labels/values manually. What would really be better though is having a dimension table in your database with you genders in.

Comment: Actaully I already test the query in SSMS and it's work!
 I think the Error beacuse Report builder is trying to put the result of Parameter into a bit field.. I will try to make it manually

Comment: If you don't have any luck,  edit your question to show where this is being used and in what context, show all your datatypes in parameters, database tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Either Report builder is trying to put the result of that case statement into a bit field, or it has an expression that is expecting a bit field that is using this field. instead of replacing the original field, add a new field with the result of your case statement and change the expression where you display it to use this field instead of the old field.

```
select customer_id
    ,first_name
    ,last_name
    ,customer_gender as gender 
    ,case when customer_gender=0 then 'Man' 
    when customer_gender=1 then 'women'
    else null as genderText 
    ,phone
    ,email
    ,city
    from [customers]
```

Comment: Can you please explain more in details